# Adding a Node in a Singly linked lists (supports adding in front, end and middle)

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write an "add" function that takes in the value held in the node (denoted 'n'), and the position the node is to be added into the linkedlist (denoted 'pos').

I have seen code where there are 3 separate add functions - addAtBeginning, addAtMiddle, addAtEnd, but I want one add function that does all of these.

I have written code for the add(int n, int pos), but it is not giving me my expected output.

For instance, in my main, i have:

```
LinkedList num;
num.add(5,1);


num.add(6,2);

num.add(7,2);
num.printList();
```

And I am expecting output: 5 7 6, (as the 7 will get shifted into the second position, and the 6 will then shift to the third position), except I am getting output: 5 6 7, where the 7 is added to the 3rd position.

Also, I have already written my Node class and LinkedList class. I have been testing my functions in these classes in small increments, and everything else seems to be fine except for my add function.

```
Node * newNode = new Node();

newNode->setValue(n); //Node gets value n

int i=1; //ie. first position is 1, not 0

Node * current = head;

if (current == nullptr) //ie. then new node IS the head
{
    head = newNode;
    head->next=nullptr;
    return;
}

if (current->next==nullptr) //adding to end of list
{

    current->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

}
else //if inserting Node at middle, (neither at beginning or end)
{


    while ( i<pos && current->next != nullptr) //traverse thru list
    {
        current=current->next;
        i = i+1;
    }

    Node * oldNext = current->next; 

    current -> next = newNode;

    newNode -> next = oldNext;



}
```

There are no error messages when I compile.

Comment: If the user asks for a node to be inserted in position 6 and there are less than five nodes, where should you insert the node? Should you insert the node?

Comment: How does `if (current->next==nullptr) //adding to end of list` work? `current->next` only inspects node 2. What if the end of the list is node 3?

Comment: Recommendation: Draw pictures. Start with an empty list. Draw an unconnected node.  Draw all of the connections you need to make to add this node into the list. Then redraw the list  step by step as you add a node to the end, Ans then again as you insert a node at the beginning. And then again as you insert a node int the middle of the list. Those drawings should describe all of the cases. Then see if there is any duplication in the steps you had to perform that you can exploit to reduce the number of different cases you have to cover.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little problem in your while condition which is decribed below:

```
i=1;
while ( i<pos && current->next != nullptr) //traverse thru list
{
    current=current->next;
    i = i+1;
}
```

Now think of this scenario where I want to insert the node at the place of 6, which is at pos 2.

[image: Vivid Idea]

According to your code, my **pos** will be 2 right?
Here is where the problem is occurring according to your code:

> while(i

What will happen is

- when i =1, i< pos and your current will shift to the next node of the head.
- Now i has become 2, because of i=i+1;
- Now i is not less than pos, so it goes out of the loop, keeping in mind your current node is pointing to the next node of the head.

> Node * oldNext = current->next;
>
> ```
> current -> next = newNode;
>
> newNode -> next = oldNext;
> ```

What's happening here is your old next is pointing to the 3rd node, since the current node is 2nd node.

You need to fix it by changing the loop condition so that the loop stops at **i< pos-1** the previous node from where it needs to be changed.

Comment: Or simply use a *pointer-to-pointer* storing the node at the current address in the list and setting the next pointer to the current [Linus on understanding pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: Yeah even that can but i was trying to point out where he might have gone wrong and made him understand that

Comment: No dings, you have a good answer, I was just passing other info along. (and killer job on the artwork -- an 8.5x11 sheet of paper and a pencil is the best way to learn lists) Here is a short example [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write separate condition for insertion at end. All you need to do is

1. First, check if it will be head node(by checking if position ==1).
2. Otherwise, just go to position one less than the position you want to insert like if insertion is at 5th then go to 4th and then do as follow.
   Let us assume that we are traversing the list by temp2 and the node to  be inserted is node temp1. Now temp2 is at 4th position. So in temp1->next put temp2->next. At this moment both are pointing to required 5th position. Now just break the link between temp2 and position by strong temp1 in temp2->next. Below is the implementation.

```
NODE* insert_n(NODE* head,int data,int position)
{
    int i;
    NODE* temp1 = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp1->data=data;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    if(position==1)
    {
        temp1->next = head;

        head = temp1;
        return head;
    }
    NODE* temp2 = head;
    for(i=0;i<position-2;i++)
    {
        temp2= temp2->next;
    }
    temp1->next =temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
    return (head);
}
```